# event can't run in android ( get errors)

Tags: java, android

I recently use android studio instead of eclipse.
but somthing is wrong!
these are main java code that run currectly in eclipse but now get errors!

```js
    package com.example.amir.myapplicationeeee;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity  {


        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
```

**setOnClickListener** is hilighed red and **error ";" excepted** showed when want to runnin app in virtual device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code you provide here is exactly the same as you have in your project, then you should just add '}' on the end of your code - it closes the MainActivity class.

You should also have evertyhing implemented inside onCreate() method.

So it should look like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            startActivity(new 
            Intent(this,Main2Activity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
  }
}
```